# using IF statement on JSON data goes wrong (Android Kotlin)

Tags: android, json, if-statement, kotlin, openweathermap

I'm trying to display the weather forecast for 5 days but the openweathermap gives me the weather for 5 days/3 hours. What I want to do is to display only the weather at 15:00.

I'm using an if statement with one of the date&time and if you see my emulator it displays the same date and time many times and also displays the whole JSON file as empty texts. Any idea on this please?
[image]

**Here is my if statement**

```
if(weatherFor.dt_txt=="2018-08-21 00:00:00") {
            holder?.view?.textWeatherDataForecast?.text = "${weatherFor.weather.map { it.description }.joinToString(",")} on ${date}"
            holder?.view?.tempTextForecast?.text = weatherFor.main.temp.toString() + "°C"

        }
```

Comment: could you paste a sample response?

Comment: @karthikprasad What do you mean?(sorry i'm new to this)

Comment: can you share your ForecastWeatherList object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are couple of things you have to change.

1. IF statement which you have added just set the texts for condition and leave the rest with Default strings. For that, one hack to change the code like below. This will remove your extra TextViews.

   ```
   if(weatherFor.dt_txt=="2018-08-21 00:00:00") 
   {
          holder?.view?.textWeatherDataForecast?.text = "${weatherFor.weather.map { it.description }.joinToString(",")} on ${date}"
       holder?.view?.tempTextForecast?.text = weatherFor.main.temp.toString() + "°C"

   }
   else
   { 
        holder?.view?.visibility = View.GONE
   }
   ```

But Ideally you have to filter your response to have only 15:00 weather data in the list. you can google how to filter list using list.filter{predicate} method.

2. Parsing date has to be done in a way to get 15:00:00 time and add if condition just for 15:00:00

   ```
    val localDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
   val dt_time: String = localDateFormat.format(date)

    if(dt_time == "15:00:00"){
           // your set holder text goes here
    }
   ```

Edited:

Add a var to your adapter class

```
    lateinit var weatherList: List<ForecastWeatherList>
```

Add a init block

```
    init{
        weatherList = forecastfeed.list.filter{ //add your condition here this should plain condition which gives true or false like it.dt_txt =="15:00:00" }
    }
```

Inside your getItemCount() replace

```
    weatherList.count()
```

Comment: Oh thanks so much!!!The problem now is that it displays what i want but it has a big white gap.How can we not add at allthe elements if the time is not 3.00 o'clock?

Comment: you have to  filter the list content with the time. Edited the answer. Please Accept and Upvote the answer if it helps.